# Show Side By Side Revisions in Reopen Queue

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen

Due to recent changes in the algorithm for putting questions in the Reopen Queue, a bunch of old, edited questions are being dumped in the queue.

There is a problem though, in order to see the revisions made to the question, you have to navigate away from the page (or spawn a new tab) to see the revision.

Wouldn't it make sense for the default behavior when a post appears in the Reopen Queue as the result of an edit be showing the side by side of the revisions?

Comment: You should vote to reopen the question based on whether the question, as it currently stands, is appropriate for the site. The revision history has almost nothing to do with it (beyond satisfying your curiosity).

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 While I agree in principal, if I can look at a question, and see that only a line changed or a minor grammatical error was fixed, or even that a tag was changed I'm not going to waste my time reading it to see if it should be reopened.

Comment: That would be incorrect - some questions are incorrectly closed due to misunderstandings, etc., and should be reopened, even if the edits are only minor.

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 The edits will show you whether it was a serious attempt to fix the question or just a ploy to get it onto the reopen queue.

Comment: @ChrisF - Should users be encouraged to skip a question, *without reading it*, because the edits are "too minor" (blind acceptance of the previous close votes)? Doesn't that defeat the point of a "re-view"?

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 the point of this queue (As I understand it) is to get new eyes on questions that have been edited. If the question is closed, and the edit is minor, why would we want to reopen it?

Comment: @ChrisF - I also don't see the point of knowing whether it was a "serious attempt" or not... either it's appropriate for the site or it's not. I don't think users should be encouraged to reopen a question becauase of "Awwww.... he really tried hard. Let's throw him a bone."

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 I understand (and agree with) your argument. I was just trying to point out that knowing what the edits to the question were could help when deciding whether to reopen or not.

Comment: @waxeagle - I have accidentally [caused questions to be closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188408/why-arent-these-give-me-teh-regexz-questions-closed#comment580221_188408) which should not have been via the Meta effect. When those questions were voted to be reopened, it would have been inappropriate to ignore them because "the edits were too minor".

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 voted to reopen, and entered the reopen queue via edit are two very different things in my mind.

Comment: @waxeagle - Ah... I hadn't noticed that you could differentiate between votes to reopen and questions which were edited. This makes more sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to navigate away from the page to see the revision though - there are 'tabs' directly underneath the action buttons for `Question (revised)` and `Revision`. Yes, it could probably be clearer that this is what they are (considering they are selectable tabs, they should probably look like selectable tabs!) but the option is present.

> [image]